# Google Analytics: Source of Direct acquisitions?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that received about 1,800 sessions over the course of last week. According to Google Analytics, 1,500 of these sessions are Direct (mostly new sessions), 200 Referral, 60 Organic, 40 Social. This has been the case for about 2 months now.

If I understand GA correctly, "Direct" means that people are typing the URL in directly. I could be wrong, but I find this hard to believe. I suspect that they are finding the site through other sites but the referrals are not showing up.

Is it possible I've missed a setting in GA, or am I not interpreting the data correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct basically means they don't have a referrer. It does include bookmarks, typed in urls but can include organic searches or referrals from other sites where the browser didn't correctly identify the source. 
Some good info on it here [searchengineland.com](http://searchengineland.com/60-direct-traffic-actually-seo-195415)